# what is diference wp_get_attachment_url / wp_get_attachment_src / get_post_thumbnail_id?

Tags: php, wp-query

**this is code exemple
I need a gallery of images, small photos down, clicking shows an image above. So far I can not open large image. **

`<li><a data-image-id="'.$photo_id.'" href="'. get_permalink($photo_id).'">
<img data-image-id="'.$photo_id.'" class="thumbnail" src="'.get_the_post_thumbnail('small_thumbnail').'"></a></li>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There no WordPress function wp_get_attachment_src when you want to get answer you should clear your questions and also descriptive

I am giving you explanation of you question.
you what is difference wp_get_attachment_url / wp_get_attachment_src / get_post_thumbnail_id?

**wp_get_attachment_url($id)**

Returns a full URI for an attachment file or false on failure.
Here id is attachment post id

**Example**

```
echo wp_get_attachment_url( $id ); 
echo wp_get_attachment_url( 12 );
$example_url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
echo '<div style="background-image:url('.$example_url.');"></div>';
```

**wp_get_attachment_image_src()**

return array value of image attribute

**Example**

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src( int $attachment_id, string|array $size = 'thumbnail', bool $icon = false )

$image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id = 8 );
if ( $image_attributes ) : ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $image_attributes[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $image_attributes[2]; ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

**get_post_thumbnail_id()**
return featured image id

**Example:**

```
get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id)
$post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
```

**Now Solution of your problem**

I guess $photo_id is your post id

```
<li><a data-image-id="'.$photo_id.'" href="'. get_permalink($photo_id).'">
<img data-image-id="'.$photo_id.'" class="thumbnail" src="'.get_the_post_thumbnail( $photo_id, 'thumbnail', array( 'class' => 'alignleft' ) );.'"></a>
</li>
```

for more information follow the codex:

[get_post_thumbnail_id()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id)

[wp_get_attachment_image_src()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/)

[wp_get_attachment_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_url/)